# Mockito argument to a private method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is my sample service class:

```
class Service {

    @Inject
    private TestDao dao;

    public void method() {
        //Other logic
        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
        privateMethod(list);
        //Other logic
    }

    private void privateMethod(List<SomeClass> list) {
        dao.save(list);
    }
}
```

If I mock dao using Mockito, then how can I test the number of calls to dao.save method? When I tried with verify, I have to give the list object. But I am not seeing any way to get that object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: With Mockito you can just say if the method is called with _any_ `List`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Show us how you are trying to setup your test, but @fgb below has one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `anyList()` matcher if you don't care about exactly what list your method is being called with. For example, if you want to verify the `save()` method was called exactly thrice:

```
verify(dao, times(3)).save(anyList())
```

If you want to make further assertions about what list `save()` was called with, use [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

An example usage of `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
ArgumentCaptor<List> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
verify(dao, times(3)).save(argument.capture());
List secondValue = argument.getAllValues().get(1); // captured value when the method was called the second time
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use ArgumentCaptor in this scenario. Here I am using a list. Also if privateMethod() is called multiple times, what should be the verify value?

Comment: @Ani the contents of the list depends on your application, and what you expect it to looks like at the end of your test. I'll edit the answer to include sample usage of `ArgumentCaptor`

Answer (score 1):

Call verify with `Matchers.anyList()`:

```
verify(dao).save(Matchers.anyList());
```

Comment: and if you want to avoid some compile warnings, there's always `anyListOf(SomeClass.class)`